# PHPMailer not sending when changed internet connection

Tags: php, phpmailer

I just wanna clear out. **This Code is Working.** But somehow I have a problem. I'm just a university student and I'm including this phpmailer for my email verification in the registration part of my project. In my house, this code is working. But, when I move to our university about one city away, the php mailer is now failing to send Email and it says "SMTP error()". My friends guess that since I moved location and changed internet connection, the error might be with the HOST and PORT. Is there any other way to make PHPMailer working without regards to my IP address, or my location, or my internet connection??

I can't see the answer within the link

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

As I said before, this code used to work already. It's just that it does not function if I move to other location or other internet connection.

I hope somebody can help me with regards to this matter.
I guess it's within the PORT and HOST.

This is my code:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();  

$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "cspgryffindor@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "cspgryffindor123"; 

$mail->setFrom('cspgryffindor@gmail.com', 'CSPGryffindor');
$to=$email;
$mail->From     = "no-reply@web.com";
$mail->AddAddress($to);  
$mail->AddReplyTo("no-reply@web.com","no-reply");
//$subject = "this is s1ubject";
//$msg="this is msg";
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 150; 
if(!$mail->send()) 
{
  //  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
   // echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```

Comment: Your SMTP is google, so this one is not changing. Please provide more information about error, because changing location could not break your code. Also - do you use same computer at home and at uni?

Comment: Have you tried SMTPDebug? What error does it show?

Comment: Have you enabled two-factor authentication in your Google account? Whatever, the trouble-shooting guide you link explains how to enable debug output but I have the impression you haven't tried that part.

Comment: Can you try $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; and provide us with the result?

Comment: Justinas, yes. Im using same laptop in computer and university. only changing the internet connection. at home im using my home's internet and at university, my friends internet connection in mobile through tethering hotspot

Comment: Its weird because it works LOL because im here in my house LOL

Comment: Mirakurun, this is the message when message successful: it works because im in my house LOL

Comment: Your code is based on an old example, so make sure you're using the latest PHPMailer. I suggest basing your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer. Also, since you've looked at the troubleshooting guide, show all the tests you did and the results you got; you've not provided enough information here, and all the non-answers posted so far duplicate what's in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Your new provider may have blocked the SMTP port, some of them do to prevent spam.
You should check on their FAQ if they do.

Unrelated but if your password is really `cspgryffindor123`, now is a good time to change it

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA you checked that out. Its a dummy account for sending email only HAHAHAHA

Comment: I mean. is there a way to chekc if the smtp port is blocked from my new internet provider?

Comment: Google your ISP name with "smtp blocked" and you will most likely find the answer very quickly

Answer (score 0):

This could be your university blocking all SMTP connections like mine did.

To find out, try using your mobile connection or another connection other than your university connection. If it's working in your home, it should be with a regular connection.

Comment: we're using a tethering hotspot from my classmate. its not from the university